# Android: Draw bitmap to left corner

Tags: android

I am drawing a bitmap on a canvas using this code:

canvas.drawBitmap(newImage, 0 , 0, null);

How do I place the bitmap to the bottom left of the canvas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `canvas.drawBitmap(newImage, 0 , YourScreenHeight-YourBitmapHeight, null);`

For getting screen's Height and Width use

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    width = display.getWidth();  
    height = display.getHeight();
```

Hope be useful for you.

Comment: Nearly there,  canvas.drawBitmap(newImage, 0 , canvas.getHeight()-newImage.getHeight(), null);